# Ford-Fulkerson algorithm running in pseudo-polynomial time

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Consider a graph with $n$ nodes and  $m = \mathcal{O}(n^2)$ edges. The maximum capacity among all edges is denoted by $C$. The running time is given by: $\mathcal{O}(nmC)$

If I consider the input size in bits, it can be stated as: $\mathcal{O}(n \log n + m \log n + m \log C)$

Denote $v:= \log n, b:= \log C $.

Then it holds: $\mathcal{O}(nv+ m (v+b))$

Why can I rewrite the running time in the following way: $\mathcal{O}(mn2^b)$

Why does $2^v \leq C2^b$  hold?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the L.H.S. is $\mathcal{O}(n \log n + m \log n + m \log C)$.

It is easy to see the following three inequalities:

1. $n \log n \in \mathcal{O}(mn2^b)$
2. $m \log n \in \mathcal{O}(mn2^b)$
3. $m \log C \in \mathcal{O}(mn2^b)$

Therefore, $\mathcal{O}(n \log n + m \log n + m \log C) \in \mathcal{O}(mn2^b)$.